# Duplicate but different Windows Uninstalls in Registry

Tags: windows, uninstall

I am trying to understand the difference between GUID and non GUID keys in HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall.

Some things have a GUID key and a non GUID key, with very different UninstallStrings. For example, Autodesk Revit has a good UninstallString in the GUID key

```
MsiExec.exe /X{7346B4A0-1900-0510-0000-705C0D862004})
```

But in the non GUID key the UninstallString is actually a Patch string I think.

```
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2019\Setup\Setup.exe /P {7346B4A0-1900-0510-0000-705C0D862004} /M RVT /LANG en-US)
```

But others, like Autodesk Desktop App don't have a GUID key, and the UninstallString in the non GUID key is good.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Autodesk Desktop App\removeAdAppMgr.exe
```

I am wondering, is this normal, or perhaps something goofy only Autodesk does? And, is there a good Microsoft resource detailing what information is expected in the various Uninstall folders? Thus far I can't find anything detailed.

EDIT:
On a similar note, I am finding Microsoft doing duplicates too, but not GUID vs not. Here are three different Uninstalls with the same DisplayName, but three different GUIDs referenced. Further, these are all x64 installs, but are found in WOW6432Node. Frustrating.

```
Visual C++ 2008 - x64 (KB958357) - v9.0.30729.177
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msiexec.exe /x {8CCEA24C-51AE-3B71-9092-7D0C44DDA2DF} /qb+ REBOOTPROMPT=""

Visual C++ 2008 - x64 (KB958357) - v9.0.30729.177
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msiexec.exe /x {C3A57BB3-9AA6-3F6F-9395-6C062BDD5FC4} /qb+ REBOOTPROMPT=""

Visual C++ 2008 - x64 (KB958357) - v9.0.30729.177
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msiexec.exe /x {F6F09DD8-F39B-3A16-ADB9-C9E6B56903F9} /qb+ REBOOTPROMPT=""
```

Comment: Microsoft always tends to get a bit creative with their own deployment. I believe those are different "aspects" of the same core Microsoft runtime (the Visual C++ 2008 runtime - which accompanies a specific version of Visual Studio - not sure which version). These runtimes are needed for some - even most - C++ applications compiled with the mentioned version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

When an developer creates an application, they typically choose a method to install it.  One popular option is to use Windows Installer and therefore create a MSI. A MSI file is essentially a database which tells Windows Installer how to install the software, i.e. files to drop, reg keys to create, services to create etc.  Popular tools for authoring MSI files are [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) or [InstallShield](https://www.flexera.com/products/installation/installshield.html).

As part of authoring a MSI the product should be assigned a unique GUID called the ProductCode.  It is this product code you see under the Uninstall key.  The UninstallString value uses the ProductCode as Windows Installer can use this to uninstall the application using the /X switch.

The developer may choose not to use Windows Installer and write their own installer.  To have it appear in Programs and Features though, the developer will need to manually create the Uninstall keys for the application. At a minimum they would need to set the DisplayName and UninstallString ([ref](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040709-00/?p=38493)). It's unlikely they would create a GUID to identify the application but they could.

If the developer created a custom installer then the developer also needs to supply some method to uninstall the application.  As a result, most developers create a separate uninstall application, which is pointed to from the UninstallString.  This application could also be used to present an option to modify, repair or uninstall the application.

It's really the preference of the developer.

Comment: Broken link to Mr. Raymond Chen - I couldn't find it on Wayback either. Maybe a copy / paste hiccup?

Comment: fixed the link.

Answer (score 0):

Good answer already posted, I will still post what I started writing before your question got deleted earlier.

The **`GUID`** keys are generally **`Windows Installer setups`** (files with **`*.MSI`** extension) - the aging standard for Microsoft deployment in  heavy use in corporations.

There are many different kinds of installers, but they are generally wrapped as `setup.exe` files or `MSI files` or newer kinds of installer formats such as `APPX` (already obsolete), `MSIX` (emerging), etc... There really are many possibilities.

**AutoDesk** looks to be using a legacy style `setup.ex`e installer that is not based on `Windows Installer`, although it is still possible that the `setup.exe` that is pointed to is a wrapper that kicks off a Windows Installer package.

I will add some links below to information on various types of setups and tasks involved when dealing with setups (such as file extraction).

---

***Some Links***:

- [Extract MSI from EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe/24987512#24987512) (lots of further links)
- [Simple list view of most used deployment tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840) (for Windows Installer)
- [More comprehensive link list of deployment tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624070/how-to-create-windows-installer/49632260#49632260) (of all kinds)
- [How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup)
- [Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933)

There are many other links embedded in these answers to similar stuff.